# Python dict values overwritten in loop

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I have a mysql table of text fields which contain lists and dicts in string format.

I want to have these in a dictionairy. I'm using pymysql with the DictCursor.

This is my code :

```
    data = {}
    temp = {}

    cursor = dbconn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "select * from table1"
    cursor.execute(query)
    r = cursor.fetchall()

    for result in r:
        print(result)
        temp['names'] = ast.literal_eval(result['names'])  # list of strings
        temp['symbols'] = ast.literal_eval(result['symbols']) # list of strings      
        temp['country'] = result['country'] # string

        data[result['id']] = temp

     print(data)
```

I have 2 rows in my table, the print-statement in the loop prints out the rows perfect as a dict one by one. But the print(data) prints out a dict which has twice the second dict.

I have no clue to why this is happening, can someone explain this to me?

Comment: `temp` is always a reference to the same dictionary object, you never make a copy or a new empty dictionary. Why did you expect different behaviour.

Comment: `data[result['id']] = temp.copy()` that'd work

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to move the creation of the `temp` dictionary inside the loop:

```
data = {}  # dict data still created here

# other stuff

for result in r:
    print(result)
    temp = {}  # create new dict here
    temp['names'] = ast.literal_eval(result['names'])  # list of strings
    temp['symbols'] = ast.literal_eval(result['symbols']) # list of strings      
    temp['country'] = result['country'] # string

    data[result['id']] = temp

print(data)  # should show different dicts, one for each result
```